Can not start system: error while loading shared libraries libzstd.so.1
In an attempt to fix a non-working Firefox, I played litle bit with libzstd.so.1 file. I backed up the original file and then created a symbolic link to libzstd.so.1.5.5 in both the /usr/lib/ and /usr/local/lib/ folders. now I'm unable to reboot the system and I'm getting the error below.
/lib/systemd/systemd-udevd: error while loading shared libraries: libzstd.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Gave up waiting for root file system device. common problems:
- Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
- Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
- Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! UUID=155........... does not exist. Dropping to a shell!

BusyBox V1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-7ubuntu3) buikt-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of buit-in commands

(initramfs) _

I've tried to used a bootable USB drive to access the system folders and restored the original file from the backup, but the error persists. Additionally, the keyboard doesn't work in the initramfs.
Ubuntu version: 22.04.4
I would greatly appreciate any ideas or suggestions to resolve this issue.
Thank you!

When you copied the correct libzstd.so.1.x.x back from backup, did you remake the symbolic link as well? Have you removed ALL traces of your "playing" from /usr/local/lib? Did you run (sudo) ldconfig after everything was back in place?

The file libzstd.so.1 was initially without a symbolic link. I tried to put everything back in the lib folder. However, I didn't run the 'ldconfig' command, instead, I rebooted the system. Maybe this is why it crashed after the reboot. Now, I can access my folders only using the bootable USB stick. Is there a way to fix the initiation of the shared libraries without reinstalling the systems !?

There should be a symlink like /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzstd.so.1 -> libzstd.so.1.4.8 mapping the name the executable looks for (libzstd.so.1) to an actual shared object file provided by the current libzstd1 package

Yes, you are right. The file with symlink exits inside /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ but I'm still getting the same message. I found the 3 files libzstd.so , libzstd.so.1 and the same with version extension in 3 locations: /usr/lib , /usr/local/lib and /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu. The symlink to libzstd.so.1.4.8 exist only in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/. In the other 2 folders, no symlinks are indicated and the higher version is libzstd.so.1.5.5
